# EIP-2612 Permit Signature Phishing Scam

Tags: erc-721, signature, phishing, permit

I have fallen for a phishing scam which resulted in drainage of a single asset from my wallet after signing a permit signature request via browser wallet.

Going back to the phishing site I can see that the signature request includes an essentially unlimited amount of tokens with approved spender as a malicious contract and a very long expiry date.

What I would be grateful to find out is:

1. can this signature be reused repeatedly until its expiry date or is it essentially void now that it has been used once by the malicious contract?
2. no other typed of asset have been drained from the same wallet - could this happen in the future if, for example the malicious contract was altered (and the permit is still valid as per my first question)?

Many thanks for any help.